# Clickhouse - TTL - merge_with_ttl_timeout does not affect column ttl

Tags: clickhouse, ttl

I tried to make an experimentation on column ttl. To do that I created a table with low ttl columns and to change ttl frequency I added merge_with_ttl_timeout as 5 seconds. But table never(~ 1 hour) got updated. Even if I changed global ttl timeout from config file like below It didn't help.

```
<merge_tree>            
    <merge_with_ttl_timeout>10</merge_with_ttl_timeout>
</merge_tree>
```

Checked with:

```
select * from system.merge_tree_settings where name like '%ttl%';
```

Table ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table
(
    d DateTime,    
    a Int TTL d + INTERVAL 5 SECOND,
    b Int TTL d + INTERVAL 10 SECOND,
    c String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(d)
ORDER BY d
SETTINGS merge_with_ttl_timeout=5;
```

Manuel commands to force ttl update (working separately):

1. option : `ALTER TABLE example_table MODIFY COLUMN b String TTL d + INTERVAL 2 SECOND;`
2. option : `ALTER TABLE example_table MATERIALIZE TTL;`

On the other hand table ttl works like a charm (Its updated on time):

```
CREATE TABLE example_table2
(
    d DateTime,    
    a Int,
    b Int,
    c String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(d)
TTL d + INTERVAL 6 SECOND 
ORDER BY d
SETTINGS merge_with_ttl_timeout=5;
```

To summarize I want to observe column ttl is working automatically, how can I achieve that ?

Clickhouse version: 20.12.5.14

Answer (score 0):

Maybe perform

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE example_table2 FINAL;
```

before every SELECT, as suggested here [TTL documentation](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#mergetree-table-ttl).

Comment: Thank you but I expect it to be done automatically. Even calling this command manually do nothing in my case. Did you have a chance to try it ?

Comment: As stated in documentation "Data with an expired TTL is removed when ClickHouse merges data parts.

When ClickHouse see that data is expired, it performs an off-schedule merge. To control the frequency of such merges, you can set merge_with_ttl_timeout. If the value is too low, it will perform many off-schedule merges that may consume a lot of resources.

If you perform the SELECT query between merges, you may get expired data. To avoid it, use the OPTIMIZE query before SELECT." - so removing expired data is preformed when merge occurs. As far as I know, you can't control this event.